# Unable to get WF Service metadata when BufferedReceive is enabled for Net.Msmq

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflowservice

I have a WF service hosted in AppFabric IIS 7/WAS. It is configured for Net.Msmq - this works fine. The client consumes the service fine. If I change the WorkflowService to allow BufferedReceive, then I can no longer navigate to the xamlx to get metadata. The error is as follows:

*

> "The contract 'IInstructionServices' has at least one operation
>   annotated with 'ReceiveContextEnabledAttribute', but the binding used
>   for the contract endpoint at address
>   'net.msmq://localhost/private/CSDInstructionProcessing/Instructions.xamlx'
>   does not support required binding property 'IReceiveContextSettings'.
>   Please ensure that the binding used for the contract supports the
>   ReceiveContext capability"

*
Any clues why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. This was because the queue was not transactional, and the ExactlyOnce was set to false.